# combine two strings in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, string-concatenation

I have a `list1` like this,

```
list1 = [('my', '1.2.3', 2),('name', '9.8.7', 3)]
```

I want to get a new `list2` like this (joining first element with second element's second entry);

```
list2 = [('my2', 2),('name8', 3)]
```

As a first step, I am checking to join the first two elements in the tuple as follow,

```
for i,j,k in list1:
    #print(i,j,k)
    x = j.split('.')[1]
    y = str(i).join(x)
    print(y)
```

but I get this

```
2
8
```

I was expecting this;

```
my2
name8
```

what I am doing wrong? Is there any good way to do this? a simple way..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
y = str(i) + str(x)
```

it should works.

Answer (score 4):

The `str(i).join(x)`, means that you see `x` as an iterable of strings (a string is an iterable of strings), and you are going to construct a string by adding `i` in between the elements of `x`.

You probably want to `print('{}{}'.format(i+x))` however:

```
for i,j,k in list1:
    x = j.split('.')[1]
    print('{}{}'.format(i+x))
```

Comment: maybe is better to use str(n) for integer value before concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for x in list1:
   print(x[0] + x[1][2])
```

or

```
for x in list1: 
   print(x[0] + x[1].split('.')[1])
```

output

```
# my2
# name8
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this via f strings and list comprehension, though it'll be pretty rigid.

```py
list_1 = [('my', '1.2.3', 2),('name', '9.8.7', 3)]

# for item in list_1
# create tuple of (item[0], item[1].split('.')[1], item[2])
# append to a new list
list_2 = [(f"{item[0]}{item[1].split('.')[1]}", f"{item[2]}") for item in list_1]

print(list_2)
```

List comprehensions (and dict comprehensions) are some of my favorite things about python3

https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3

Comment: Simple and to the point. Note that you don't really need to use f-strings here; `[(item[0]+item[1].split('.')[1], item[2]) for item in list_1]` should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Going with the author's theme,

```
list1 = [('my', '1.2.3', 2),('name', '9.8.7', 3)]

for i,j,k in list1:
    extracted = j.split(".") 
    y = i+extracted[1] # specified the index here instead 
    print(y)
```

```
my2
name8

[Program finished]
```